# log raw SOAP messages in grails with apache-cxf does not work

Tags: grails, logging, soap, log4j, cxf

I'm using grails plugin apache-cxf v1.1.4 with grails 2.2.4. I used wsdl-to-java to generate java stubs. Communication via SOAP is working great, but I can't force plugin to log SOAP messages to console.
I tried adding to my log4j configuration this from documentation:

> info 'org.apache.cxf'

but it gives me nothing in logs.

If I set logging level of 'org.apache.cxf' to DEBUG, I get many logs from cxf plugin but still no raw SOAP messages. What am I missing?